# java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataBinder is already initialized with ConversionService

Tags: java, spring

I am getting the above error message when I include the following in the tms-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

together with:

```
class TrainingInstructorController {
    private ConversionService conversionService;
    //Autowiring the ConversionService we declared in the context file above.

    @InitBinder
    public void registerConversionServices(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.setConversionService(conversionService);
    } 
}
```

Removing the `mvc:annotation-driven` will fix the problem.

Why is this happening? What is the fix?

Comment: Could you show your `tms-servlet.xml`?

Comment: There is a default conversion service which is always automatically registered with the `WebDataBinder`. If you want to customize the conversion service you need to register it with the `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. It isn't, currently, possible to have a different `ConversionService` for a single controller.